# Magento 2 : Create comma seperated sku filter for custom product grid

Tags: magento2, sku, custom-admin-grid

I am using Magento ver. 2.4.4.
I have a custom grid, displaying the below fields data.

**item_id,
rma_id  ,product_sku    ,order_item_id  ,reason_id  resolution_id   ,condition_id.**

**I want to create a filter for SKU, where we can put comma-separated or space-separated SKU & it will show results based on it.**

Is there any way it can be done?
Kindly let me know your thoughts on this.

Comment: Facebook SDK does not support PHP 8.x https://github.com/facebookarchive/php-graph-sdk, so you may want to try using a fork like https://github.com/joelbutcher/facebook-php-graph-sdk

Comment: switch out the FB SDK for this one github.com/joelbutcher/facebook-php-graph-sdk ... in composer.json  change` facebook/graph-sdk` to `joelbutcher/facebook-graph-sdk`

Comment: Any thoughts on this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i correct understand, you are using UI Component. Following example how to add multiply SKU filter on product grid. I hope you can properly add to your custom grid

**Acme/StackExchange/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_listing.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <filters name="listing_filters">
            <filterInput name="sku" template="ui/grid/filters/field" class="Acme\StackExchange\Ui\Component\Listing\Filter\Sku" provider="${ $.parentName }">
                <settings>
                    <dataScope>sku</dataScope>
                    <label translate="true">SKU</label>
                </settings>
            </filterInput>
        </filters>
    </listingToolbar>
    <!-- Reset default filter. Just don't define filter in your column -->
    <columns name="product_columns">
        <column name="sku">
            <settings>
                <filter>false</filter>
            </settings>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

**Acme/StackExchange/Ui/Component/Listing/Filter/Sku.php**

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Acme\StackExchange\Ui\Component\Listing\Filter;

use Magento\Ui\Component\Filters\Type\Input;

class Sku extends Input
{
    /**
     * @inheridoc
     */
    protected function applyFilter(): void
    {
        if (isset($this->filterData[$this->getName()])) {
            $value = explode(',', $this->filterData[$this->getName()]);
            $value = array_map('trim', $value);

            $filter = $this->filterBuilder->setConditionType('in')
                ->setField('sku')
                ->setValue($value)
                ->create();

            $this->getContext()->getDataProvider()->addFilter($filter);
        }
    }
}
```

**[Update]**

In example with use logic with reset filter your module should depends on original logic. In this example:

**Acme/StackExchange/etc/module.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Acme_StackExchange">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Example with the same logic, but with custom filter name

**Acme/StackExchange/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_listing.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <filters name="listing_filters">
            <filterInput name="sku_list" template="ui/grid/filters/field" class="Acme\StackExchange\Ui\Component\Listing\Filter\Sku" provider="${ $.parentName }">
                <settings>
                    <dataScope>sku_list</dataScope>
                    <label translate="true">SKU (comma)</label>
                </settings>
            </filterInput>
        </filters>
    </listingToolbar>
</listing>
```

**Result**
[image: Applied filter]

Comment: Hello @Victor, thank you for the response.

Comment: I will test it & let you know if that works, is it works for you ?

Comment: I am using default Magento's ui component & displaying data in admin grid. I have other filters too which are also custom, is there any possibility to manage them also with the file you have sent?

Comment: I have tested its not working, it shows no record when comma separated SKU are added to filter.

Comment: Provided example is tested and it's work in 2.4.4 with product grid. Please to be sure you've properly use example and you don't keep `filter` for column. Please update question with your custom listing XML and provide an example of product sku for filter you are use. Is your collection has `sku` as SKU field?

Comment: Thank you, its working fine.